# How to know if my BluetoothDevice is connected?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to check if my `BluetoothDevice` is connected to something.
If it is connected, obtain the data of the other device

I want to implement this function to my application since I need to monitor if the connection was lost or is still connected and add a visual indicator in case the connection changes.

Tried with this function but the toast shows nearby devices (not connected) constantly:

```
if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    String name = device.getName();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to view the state of the connection.  Instead you monitor for changes in the state of the bluetooth connection.  So you can register a receiver and then receive a broadcast when the device is disconnected.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
this.registerReceiver(rec, filter);

private BroadcastReceiver rec = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
       // Bluetooth is now disconnected
    }
}
```